# Lazysizes wait until image is fully loaded in background

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I am using [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) for lazy image loading. It's working fine, but I was asking myself if it is possible to load the images in the background and replace the src attribute after the real image is fully loaded.

The problem I am facing right now is, that the src attribute is replaced with the real image when visible, but on slow internet connections, the image slowly loads from top to bottom.

I would rather wait until the image has loaded in the background and then replace the src attribute to prevent the effect shown in the screenshot below.

Do I have to use another library or can I arc hieve this with lazysizes?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Image slowly loading]

Answer (score 0):

You can load an image with this code:

```
 function loadImage(url, callback) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = callback;
   img.url = url;
 }
```

Then on `callback` set your image url:

```
 var url = "http://path.to/my/image.jpg";
 loadImage(url, function() {
   document.getElementById("myimg").src = url;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

You can use the class .lazypreload to achieve this effect.